# Why is the C compiler dropping my &0xFF mask?

Tags: c++, c

I have a problem where 2 different compilers (GCC and IAR) are dropping my mask from an if of different sized variables.

I have the following code:

```
uint8_t Value2;
uint16_t WriteOffset;
bool Fail;

void test(void)
{
        uint8_t buff[100];
        uint16_t r;

        for(r=0;r<Value2+1;r++)
        {
                if(buff[r]!=(WriteOffset+r)&0xFF)
                {
                        Fail=true;
                }
        }
}
```

The if fails (goes into the {} block) when `buff[r]` ==0 and `WriteOffset+r` == 0x100.

GCC outputs the following assembly:

```
movzwl -0xc(%ebp),%eax                          ; Load 'r'->EAX
mov    -0x70(%ebp,%eax,1),%al                   ; Load 'buff[r]'->AL
movzbl %al,%edx                                 ; Move AL to (unsigned int)EDX
mov    0x4b19e0,%ax                             ; Load 'WriteOffset'->AX
movzwl %ax,%ecx                                 ; Move AX to (unsigned int)ECX
movzwl -0xc(%ebp),%eax                          ; Load 'r'->EAX
lea    (%ecx,%eax,1),%eax                       ; 'WriteOffset' + 'r'->EAX
cmp    %eax,%edx                                ; (unsigned int)'WriteOffset+r' == (unsigned int)'buff[r]'
je     0x445e28 <Test+1254>                     ; If == skip {} block
```

My question is why is the compiler dropping my `&0xFF` from the if (I have already fixed the problem with a cast, but I still do not understand why it dropped it in the first place)?

Comment: What optimization level are you compiling with? Always important especially when you add assembly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It isn't, [operator precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C++#Operator_precedence) is biting you here

You want `if( buff[r] != ((WriteOffset+r)&0xFF) )`

What you currently have is the same as `if( (buff[r]!=(WriteOffset+r)) & 0xFF )`

The precedence confusion is causing you to mask a value that can only be 0 or 1 (the result of the comparison expression) with 0xFF, so the optimizer is quite reasonably removing it.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the low precendece of the bitwise operators `&`, `|` and `^` is because `&` and `|` were added to the language before the logical operators `&&` and `||`, so they were originally used for logical expressions too - where the low precedence is generally what you do want.

Comment: Thanks,  I would have never thought that & and | where lower precedence than !=, but now it all makes sense.

Answer (score 3):

`!=` is higher precedence than `&`. I think you need an extra set of parentheses.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B has a C/C++ operator precedence table, have a look.

Answer (score 3):

Operator `!=` has higher priority than `&`. So you should write so:

```
 if(buff[r]!=((WriteOffset+r)&0xFF))
```